# jQuery function to add CSS class (nav-bar that follows users) doesn't work on FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling with a jQuery function used to show a "follow user" nav-bar at the top of the window when the user scrolls more than a "x" value. The problem is :

- Works perfectly on : Safari (Mac) and iPhone, works perfectly also on IE
- But, absolutely doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome.

I think that the problem is located in the CSS, and not in the jQuery ?

Trying to find an issue with this code makes me feel like burning in the hell. Please, help me !

Thank you in advance !

This is the CSS:

```
.shopmenu-fixed {
top: 60px;
left: 40%;
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
width: 650px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.shopmenu-fixed {
    top: 60px;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 650px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
.shopmenu-fixed {
    top: 60px;
    left: 60%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.shopmenu-fixed {
    top: 60px;
    left: 65%;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
}
}
```

And the javascript/jquery function, called in the body of a joomla module :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        // This part add a class to show the
        // navbar at the top of the window
        console.log($(window).scrollTop())
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1100) {
            $('#shop_menu').addClass('shopmenu-fixed');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 850) {
            $('#shop_menu').removeClass('shopmenu-fixed');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: set your shopmenu-fixed to be `display:block;` 80% sure its that :D

Comment: doesn't work for me :(...Thank you for your reply !